# python - how to accept arguments via command line using ArgumentParser

Tags: python, python-2.7

**Background Information**

I am writing a python script that will contain a set of methods that will be triggered via the command line.  Most functions will accept one or two parameters.

**Problem**

I've been reading up about the ArgumentParser but it's not clear to me how to write my code so that a function can be triggered using the "-" or "--" notation, and also ensure that if / when a specific function is invoked, the user is passing the correct number of arguments and type.

**Code**

Sample function inside the script:

```
def restore_db_dump(dump, dest_db):
    """restore src (dumpfile) to dest (name of database)"""
    popen = subprocess.Popen(['psql', '-U', 'postgres', '-c', 'CREATE DATABASE ' + dest_db], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, universal_newlines=True)
    print popen.communicate()
    popen.stdout.close()
    popen.wait()
    popen = subprocess.Popen(['pg_restore','-U', 'postgres', '-j', '2', '-d', 'provisioning', '/tmp/'+ dump + '.sql' ], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, u
niversal_newlines=True)
    print popen.communicate()
    popen.stdout.close()
    popen.wait()

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--restore', dest='restoredbname',action='store_const', const=restore_dump, help='Restore specified dump file as dbname.  Must supply <pathtodumpfile> and <dbname>')
    args = parser.parse_args()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Code Execution**

The help system seems to be working as you can see below, but I don't know how to write logic that forces / checks to see if "restore_dump" is triggered, the user is passing the correct parameters:

```
lab-1:/tmp# ./test-db.py -h
usage: test-db.py [-h] [-r]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help     show this help message and exit
  -r, --restore  Restore specified dump file as dbname. Must supply
                 <pathtodumpfile> and <dbname>
```

**Question**

Can someone point me in the right direction about how to add logic that will check when the restore_db_dump file is called, the right number of parameters are passed?

As far as how to "link" the -r argument so that it triggers the right function, I saw another post here on stackoverflow so I'm going to check that out.

THanks.

**EDIT 1:**

I forgot to mention that I'm currently reading: https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html - 15.4.1. Example
But it's not clear to me how to apply this to my code. It seems that in the case of the sum function the order of the parameters is the integers first and then the function name later.
In my case, I would like the function name first (as an optional arg) and then the parameters required by the function to follow.)

**EDIT 2:**

Changed the code to look like this:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parse = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='test-db.py')
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--restore', nargs=2, help='Restore specified dump file as dbname.  Must supply <pathtodumpfile> and <dbname>')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.restore:
        restore_db_dump(args.restore[0], args.restore[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And when I run it with one missing arg, it now correctly returns an error!  Which is great!!!
But I'm wondering how to fix the help so it's more meaningful.  It seems that for each argument, the system is showing the word "RESTORE".  How do I change this so that its actually a useful message?

```
lab-1:/tmp# ./test-db.py -h
usage: test-db.py [-h] [-r RESTORE RESTORE]

optional arguments:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -r RESTORE RESTORE, --restore RESTORE RESTORE
                        Restore specified dump file as dbname. Must supply
                        <pathtodumpfile> and <dbname>
```

Comment: @9769953 re: your first comment - it's not clear where I'm supposed to save / get args.dbname and args.pathtodumpfile.  This is what my question is all about.

Comment: @9769953 ok the answer you posted makes more sense.  giving it a try.  thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following:

```
def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-r', '--restore', nargs=2,
        metavar=('path-to-dump-file', 'db-name'),
        help='Restore specified dump file as dbname.  Must supply <pathtodumpfile> and <dbname>')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    if args.restore:
        restore_db_dump(args.restore[0], args.restore[1])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Notes:

- I have removed `const=`, because it's not clear whether you want a default.
- There is now a `nargs=2` parameter, so the `-r` option requires two values to be given.
- the `metavar` parameter sets the names of the arguments to `-r` in the help text.

Comment: This is great.  Makes sense and really clear!  Please see my Edit 2 for results.